# Laravel Upgrade From 5.6 to Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have a Project https://github.com/javedbaloch4/Laravel-Booking developed in `Laravel 5.6` now I want to upgrade it to `Laravel 6`. What are the steps can I directly update to 6 or first goto 5.7, 5.8 and then.

Please can guide the steps here for a quickly upgrade Thanks.

Comment: Does any of the below answers solved your question ?

Comment: Pls mark any useful answer as the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

The official framework documentation tells you exactly how to upgrade:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1 :** Remove the followings from your composer.json file

```
"laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0",
"yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^8.4"
```

**Step 2 :** Replace this line

```
"laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
```

To this

```
"laravel/framework": "^6.0",
```

**Step 3 :**  Run Following commands in order

```
composer require laravel/helpers
composer require laravelcollective/html
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-html
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-fractal
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-editor
composer update
composer dumpa
```

> Key Point to notice and understand is whenever you want to upgrade
>   make sure all the packages you're using have compatibility with correct versions of laravel and php. Check and follow the repo. on git to get notified if any new upgrades are there.

That's It, You're Good to go.

Comment: hmm not quite so easy though... lots of gotchas unless you are lucky..

Comment: Trust me man that's the one of the cheapest solution i can come up with these circumstances , unless you're freelancer you've alot of time to dig into it. We can't either rely on move folders and files manually from older to newer version of laravel that just kills alot of time. Please let me know if you've any other insights on this problem of migrating from older to newer version. I'm expecting that time will come when we just to have replace composer.json file and then run composer update and magic happens. :p

Comment: true.. on clean Laravel builds your version works really well - just saying that I've had a couple where it has broken... but your method does most of the heavy lifting... Now to find something that helps me move from React 15 to 16 :|

Comment: If we focus only on "How much change is there?" then we need to first look into directory structure, if any core folder or file move from some other place or renamed then it's way too difficult to adjust, if it's only the case of libraries, then we only need to update our `composer.json`, please let us know if you found any difficulty, or ask question about it with well framed.

Comment: Please let us know if this is resolved or not ? or does my answer any improvement or if you would have found any other way to deal with problem then please post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use https://laravelshift.com if you need any automatized solution.