# Laravel Target class [register] does not exist after migrate from version 5.8 to 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-8

I had project in `Laravel 5.8` and I created new project in `Laravel 8` and moved files with code into new project.
My routes files has route:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AccountController;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;

/* @var $router \Illuminate\Routing\Router */
$router->get('/', ['uses' => 'PageController@home', 'as' => 'home']);

$router->group(['prefix' => 'account', 'middleware' => ['register', 'no-cache', 'timezone']], function (Router $router) {
   // $router->get('/dashboard', ['uses' => 'AccountController@dashboard', 'as' => 'account.dashboard']);
    $router->get('/dashboard', [AccountController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('account.dashboard');
```

When I type `home` in in url view is displayed. But when I type /account/dashboard I get error:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [register] does not exist.
```

Something is wrong with middleware? Why first routing with PageController and home works but account.dashboard doesn't work in both cases (first is commented)

In `RouteServiceProvider` I uncommented line:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

---

Now it works, I forgot to add in `app\Http\Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...
        'admin' => AdminMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

and router cannot find `admin` prefix

Comment: Did you followed Laravel's official upgrde guide? You need to upgrade the versions iteratively (5->6->7->8). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58141833/7574023) may be useful

Comment: Yes, I did. I installed everything. My website is displayed in Laravel 8, but I have only error when I use this `$router->group(['prefix' => 'account', 'middleware' ...` section

Comment: you may check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63882034/target-class-does-not-exist-problem-in-laravel-8/63882104.

Comment: What happens if you type `account.dashboard`?

Comment: Ok, I have found, in `app\Http\Kernel.php` I forgot to add to ` protected $routeMiddleware = [ ..., 'admin' => AdminMiddleware::class,
    ];` And router cannot find `admin` prefix

Comment: You should not be upgrading your Laravel projects by creating a new project and migrating files. You should be following the Laravel upgrade guide for this exact reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Robert pointed out in the comment section, in `app\Http\Kernel.php` `'admin'` was missing. Apparently the solution was to add an item accordingly to the `$routeMiddleware` array, shown by Robert as

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...
        'admin' => AdminMiddleware::class,
    ];
```